# Showing that $\tan(\pi z) = z$ has exactly three solutions in the strip $|\Re(z)| < 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration

We can't use Rouche's theorem here directly, so we have to apply the argument principle. If $f(z) = \tan(\pi z) - z$ , then $f'(z) = \pi \sec^2(\pi z) - 1$. Choose the rectangle $\Gamma$ with endpoints $(1- \varepsilon) \pm Ri$ and $(-1 + \varepsilon) \pm Ri$, and evaluate

$$\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\oint_\Gamma \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} dz = \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\oint_\Gamma \frac{\pi \sec^2(\pi z) - 1}{\tan(\pi z) - z} dz,$$

and let $R \to \infty$.

Notice that the integrand is odd, so the integral evaluates to zero (right?). Therefore, by the argument principle $f$ has as many poles as it does zeroes. But $f(z)$ has no poles in $|\Re (z)| < 1$.

What am I missing here?

Comment: "Notice that the integrand is odd, so the integral evaluates to zero (right?)." No. $\frac{1}{z}$ is odd, the circle $\lvert z\rvert = R$ is symmetric. Don't forget that $dz$ is odd too.

Comment: In that case, we need to explicitly calculate the integral. If we choose the branch of the logarithm with branch cut the negative real axis. Since $\frac{d}{dz}\log(f) = f'/f$, I tried evaluating the integral as $\log(f(z))|^{-1+\varepsilon}_{-1-\varepsilon} = 2\pi i$; if that's correct, then $f$ has one more zero than it has poles; $\tan(pi z)$ has poles where $\cos(\pi z) = 0$, i.e., at $z = \pm 1/2$. Finally, this gives that $f(z)$ has $2 + 1 = 3$ zeros. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Daniel for pointing out my obvious mistake.

Pick the branch of the logarithm with argument in $[-\pi,\pi]$. Integrate on the rectangle from the point $-1 + \varepsilon_1 - i\varepsilon_2$ to $-1 + \varepsilon_1 + i\varepsilon_2$, following $\gamma$ counterclockwise. Since $\log(f) = f'/f$ on this section of the curve, letting $\varepsilon_1 \to 0$ and setting $\varepsilon = \varepsilon_2$, the integral comes out to

$$\begin{align}
&\log[\tan(-\pi + \pi i\varepsilon) - (-1 + i\varepsilon)] - \log[\tan(-\pi - \pi i\varepsilon) - (-1 - i\varepsilon)]\\
\rightarrow & (\log|-1| + i\pi) - (\log |-1| - i \pi) \\
= &2\pi i,
\end{align}$$

which is unchanged as $R \to \infty$. By the argument principle, $f(z)$ has one zero more than it has poles. Since $\tan(\pi z) - z$ has poles at $z = \pm \frac{1}{2}$, $f(z)$ has three zeroes in the strip, and $\tan(\pi z) = z$ has exactly three solutions in the strip $|\Re(z)| < 1$.